# Click to play/pause doesn't work in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am currently developing a website and having a problem right now
In my website I put on html5 video, and I have added an event to make user enable to pause/play by clicking the video. The event works well with Chrome and IE, but not with Mozilla. Can anybody tell me what is going on?

Here is my code

```
<div class="header-unit">
   <div id="video-container">
     <video controls autoplay loop muted class="fillWidth">
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
     </video>
   </div><!-- end video-container -->
</div><!-- end .header-unit -->
```

and this is the JS

```
$('.fillWidth').click(function(){
    this.paused?

    this.play():

    this.pause();

});
```

Btw can anybody tell me how to add big play button in the middle of the screen when the user is hovering to the video? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
$('video').trigger('play');
$('video').trigger('pause');
```

Good luck!

Comment: it is working, but the codes you provide me cant be used for Chrome and IE, what should I do? I have tried to put both of the codes, but still cant work for all of them together..

Comment: @user3814749 sorry i can't help you at the moment i will update the answer later. I suggest better a ask new question with full description. good luck!

Comment: okay thank you! 
I am looking for a JS that can run in Chrome, IE, and Mozilla! thanks!